# Is there any current use of icmp features like Address Mask Request

Tags: ipv4, ip, subnet, network, icmp

I recently looked through the ICMP packettypes and there are some packettypes which in theory allow to request information from a host like the domain name, subnetmask, timestamp,... out of curiosity I used hping3 to generate some of these packets and sent them to a windows 7 and a windows 10 machine but no answers have been sent eventhogh I explicitly allowed these requests in the firewalls of the receiving systems.

Seemingly these features have simply not beet implemented or disabled for security reasons. Is there any relevant system that will work with these message types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 6918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6918) deprecates several ICMP types:

- Alternate Host Address (Type 6)
- Information Request (Type 15)
- Information Reply (Type 16)
- Address Mask Request (Type 17)
- Address Mask Reply (Type 18)
- Traceroute (Type 30)
- Datagram Conversion Error (Type 31)
- Mobile Host Redirect (Type 32)
- IPv6 Where-Are-You (Type 33)
- IPv6 I-Am-Here (Type 34)
- Mobile Registration Request (Type 35)
- Mobile Registration Reply (Type 36)
- Domain Name Request (Type 37)
- Domain Name Reply (Type 38)
- SKIP (Type 39)

Not a straight answer but probably the best you can get.